# Оптимизация while в PHP

Tags: while, php, оптимизация

Здравствуйте,

Есть задача сделать цикл, который при каждой итерации выполняет функцию `foo()`, если она возвращает объект данных - использовать его в теле цикла, а если `false` - выйти из цикла.

Вопрос: как избавиться от повторного вызова функции в теле цикла?

```
foreach ($items as $i) {
    while(foo()) {
        $data = foo();
        //операции над данными $data
    }
}
function foo() {
    $data = Object;
    return (someCondition)?$data:false;
}
```

Comment: while ($data = foo()) {}

Comment: Это действительно выполнит функцию, сохранит результат выполнения в переменную и проверит значение переменной? Я всегда считал такую конструкцию проверкой возможности присваивания переменной (а-ля Интерпретатор:"да, функция выполнилась без ошибок, переменной могу присвоить ее результат, все Ok, идем в цикл").

Судя по всему, это действительно выполняет функцию, сохраняет результат в переменную и проверяет значение переменной. Я не правильно понимал эту конструкцию. Спасибо @Etki

Comment: At your service

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, что вообще за вакханалия происходит :)

```
<?
foreach($items as $i){
 if($data = foo()){ // Проверяем что возвращает foo()
  // Возвратился объект, делаем что нужно
 }else
  break; // Возврат false, выходим из foreach
}
```

Comment: попытаюсь объяснить вакханалию:)
Для каждого элемента массива $items нужно выполнить цикл, который проверяет что получается в результате выполнения функции foo(), если возвращается объект - обрабатываем его, если функция вернула false, то все, выходим из цикла

Comment: @undestroyer, так:  
Цикл не проверяет что возвращается (т.е., конечно, проверяет, но не в этом случае), значит нужна конструкция `if(){}else{}`.  
Нужно знать какой тип объекта возвращается - если он поддерживает интерфейс итератора, то можно его заюзать в `while(){}`, иначе - никаких циклов.  
P. S. Нужен выход из цикла или бросить текущий элемент и перейти к другому для его проверки?  
`break` выбросит вообще из цикла, а `continue` перейдёт к следующему элементу.

Comment: @TheDoctor, "Цикл не проверяет, что возвращается" - серьезно? php.net говорит иначе ( http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.while.php ): "Значение выражения expr проверяется каждый раз перед началом цикла..."

Comment: @undestroyer, читай внимательней - я в скобках написал, что, конечно же, проверяется, но не для данного случая.  
Хотя если извратится, то и тут можно, но это govnokod.ru

Comment: @TheDoctor, а как насчет конструкции `while($data = foo()) {...}`? Судя по всему, она действительно делает то, что надо. govnokod.ru?

Comment: Опять же - смотря что возвращается.  
Результат выборки из БД - отлично, вычисление числа Фибоначчи - бред и индусский код.  
Контекст выполнения очень важен, в JS я этому научился как ни в одном языке :)